# Axios GET request for form encoded data

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to make a GET request to an api I have that has a JSON Web Token for authentication and takes form-encoded data. It keeps failing with "Network Error" but when I run the same api in cURL, the proper data is returned. Below is my code usign the Axios library:

```
const token = "xxxxx";
axios.get('https://xxxxxxx.com/route', { headers: { 'Authorization': token, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }, data: {} }).then(response => {
console.log(response.data);
})
.catch((error) => {
console.log(error.message);
});
```

Working cURL request:

```
curl -X GET \
https://xxxxxxxx.com/route \
-H 'authorization: xxxxxx' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Remove data from headers

```
   const token = "xxxxx";
    axios.get('https://xxxxxxx.com/route', { headers: { 'Authorization': token, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
```